# Confidence Score of Predicted NER entities using Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to predict entities using a custom trained NER model using spacy. I read https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/8855 that confidence scores of each entity can be obtained using spancat. But I have a little confusion regarding to make that work. According to my understanding, we have to train a pipeline using spancat component. So while training, within the config file there is a segment,

```
[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","ner"]
batch_size = 1000
```

Should we have to change this to

```
[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","ner","spancat"]
batch_size = 1000
```

for the spancat to work.

Then after training, while predicting the entities from unknown text, should we have to use

```
doc = nlp(data_to_be_predicted)
spans = doc.spans["spancat"] # SpanGroup
print(spans.attrs["scores"]) # list of numbers, span length as SpanGroup
```

to get the confidence scores.

I am using spacy 3.1.3. I believe according to the documentation, this feature is rolled out by now.

Comment: It looks like you asked this same question a few days ago with a different account? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69671851/confidence-score-of-spacy-ner-custom-trained-and-pretrained-model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure there's a question in your post, but yes, the spancat is available and you can get entity scores from it.

The spancat is a different component from the ner component. So if you do this:

```
pipeline = ["tok2vec","ner","spancat"]
```

The spancat will not add scores for things your ner component predicted. You probably want to remove the ner component.

---

About usage, please see [the docs](https://spacy.io/api/spancategorizer) and [the example project](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/experimental/ner_spancat). This is how you get the score:

```
doc = nlp(text)
span_group = doc.spans["spans"] # default key, can be changed
scores = span_group.attrs["scores"]

# Note that `scores` is an array with one score for each span in the group
for span, score in zip(span_group, scores):
    print(score, span)
```

Comment: is there any usage example available to understand how it can be obtained. I am little confused over this. WIll it be possible to get like "ADAM" ---> PERSON ---> 0.92

Comment: Edited answer to include example.

Comment: @polm23 can you please provide an A-Z tutorial to address this kind of issues? How can one produce/train a spancat model out of spacy blank model and custom labels.